# "FaceBook Login" vs "FaceBook Connect"

Tags: facebook

Hello all
Please help me find **official** info about following:
1) What is "FaceBook Login"
2) What is "FaceBook Connect"
Thank you

Comment: What technology you are going to use? PHP?

Comment: asp.net. But at this moment I do investigation only (for my boss:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find everything you need there:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

For login:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

for Facebook Connect:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Facebook Login is not an official Facebook expression. The official term for this is Facebook Authentication. Facebook Connect was the expression used for the server to server technology, back when the Rest API was up to date. Now, you have to use the Graph API to do the same things. You can find the infos about the old Rest API here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/

But consider these APIs are deprecated and using them for a new development is probably not a good idea...

Answer (score -1):

I believe you're looking for https://www.facebook.com/about/login/.

You might also find this useful: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

Comment: That login link no longer works. Maybe this was intended: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/